# How to disable message sorting on Thunderbird?

Tags: windows-xp, email, thunderbird, sorting

I keep constantly clicking the "subject" sorting button, when I want to click on the newest message.

How can I disable the sorting completely? Perhaps by hacking the .exe file?

It's pretty much useless feature, the sorting I mean. I can't think of a reason why to sort them other way than by their dates.

Visual presentation of the button I am talking about:
[image]

Comment: I don't think it is possible to disable or hide it. One option is to sort on ascending Date (instead of descending as in your case). That way you won't be clicking close to the sort header. Of course you might not prefer that order. One good thing about Thunderbird is that it scrolls to show the new mail in the end.

Comment: @jaychris, seems like it is, check Andrea's answer :)

Comment: Wonderful! Extensions FTW!

Comment: @jaychris: Your comment sounds like an answer, which you should post as an answer. But, knowing it isn't a correct answer, you may choose to delete the comment instead.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/no-message-pane-sort-by-mouse/) extension (it is called *No Message Pane Sort by Mouse*); according to the description:

> No Message Pane Sort prevents accidental resorting of the message pane
> by disabling mouse button clicks on the column headers. It is still
> possible to sort messages by ctrl-clicking the header.

I tried it myself: it disables sort button and thus should be what you're searching.

Comment: Awesome. Works perfectly! Accepted/Upvoted.

Comment: Oh thank god, this was driving me crazy... +1!

Comment: Still a problem in 2016, and still a solution. Thanks :)

Comment: I hope this extension still works when TB upgrades to WebExtensions.

Comment: Amazing! I can't believe there exists something exactly for this purpose.